# Angular Datatables export buttons using cached data

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I'm running an Angular 13 application that queries an API for employees in a given country and office/branch from a form, then displays the list in a table.
I'm using angular-datatables for the table, and have included the print and export buttons for clipboard, CSV, text, excel, and pdf.

On repeated submissions of the form, the updated list of employees is displayed correctly, but only the initial data from the first submission is being exported to the various options.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="needs-validation" role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(branchSearchForm)" #branchSearchForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group row pt-3 ps-3">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-form-label">
          <label for="country-input-box" aria-label="branch">Branch</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <input id="country-input-box" name="country" type="text" class="form-control" ngModel/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row pt-3 ps-3">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-form-label">
          <label for="branch">Branch</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <input id="branch" name="branch" class="form-control" type="text" ngModel/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row pt-3 ps-3 pb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-form-label">
          <em class="small" translate>requiredField</em>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row" *ngIf="branch$ | async as branch">
    <table class="row-border hover table table-striped" *ngIf="branch.employees> 0" [dtOptions]="dataTableOptions" datatable>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th translate>ID</th>
          <th translate>First Name</th>
          <th translate>Surname</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of branch.employees">
          <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.surName}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div *ngIf="branch.employees === 0">No employees</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```ts
Branch {
    id: number;
    country: string;
    employees: Employee[];
}

Employee {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    surName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html'
}
export EmployeesFormComponent implements OnInit {
  branch$!: Observable<Branch>;

  dataTableOptions: any;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    dataTableOptions = {};
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataTableOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      processing: true,
      columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'firstName' },
        { data: 'surName' }
      ],
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'copy',   // Copy table to clipboard
        'print',  // Print table
        'csv',    // Export to CSV
        'excel',  // Export to Excel
        'pdf'     // Export to PDF
      ]
    };
  }

  onSubmit(branchSearchForm: any): void {
    const country: string = matchSearchForm.form.controls.country.value;
    const branch: string = matchSearchForm.form.controls.value;
    this.apiService.getBranchDetails(country, branch)
                   .subscribe((branch: Branch) => {
                                this.branch$ = of(branch);
                              });
  }
}
```

```ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBranchDetails(country: string, branch: string): Observable<Branch> {
    const url: string = `api/${country}/${branch}/details`;
    return this.http.get<Branch>(url);
  }
}
```

What do I need to change to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I thnink should not do the subscribe() followed with the of() call.
This is what your branch$ Observable is used for : consume directly the result of a service method. Then you create a sub component and inject the branch$ with a Pipe async.

I suggest you create a Subject Service that can broadcast the data.

Otherwise, since you use the subscribe() method, you simply could get rid of the Observable and Pipe async.

Explained here :
https://dev.to/juliandierkes/two-ways-of-using-angular-services-with-the-httpclient-51ef

Comment: thanks, I had t o rework the api response, and then I was able to assign the response directly to the observable

Comment: Excellent ! Glad you made it :)